# Custom CSS Files Not Included in Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Possibly a duplicate question, but I have searched all over and haven't found a definitive answer. My CSS files aren't being included in my Bootstrap 3 code.

Here is a sample from a header include file that is at the top of each page. The include is done through PHP.

```
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <!-- METAs -->

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="css/social-buttons.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel = "stylesheet">

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">


...
```

All these files are sourced within a CSS file and the file is accessible. I feel like everything is being included properly. Could it be an issue with including the code from a PHP file instead of raw code inline?

Comment: `including the code from a PHP` what do you mean? why here tag `php`?

Comment: @Waki this code sits insidea PHP file and that PHP file is called from within another file and the code is put into the new file.

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure (for core php project) must be

```
Main Folder
   -- css
       --all css files
   --index.php / index.html
```

Comment: Looks about right. Only thing is my index.php doesn't use that name specifically. could this cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your paths are correct, it really shouldn't be a problem.
Let's assume your directory is like so:

```
/includes
    /header.php (calls the below css files)
/css
    /style.css
    /bootstrap.css
    /others.css
/index.php
```

In your index file, your include would be:

```
<?php include ('includes/header.php');?>
```

In your header.php:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> (etc, your other css files)
```

Comment: my include looks like     <?php 

 include 'header.php';

?> could the parenthesis be an issue?

Comment: both includes with or without the brackets can work. So no, that isn't the issue.